# Woocommerce change the price of products in the database

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sql

I'm trying to adjust the price of products in the database. I need to customize products that have custom taxonomy manufactory with id 270.

I can change a simple product with this code:

```
    UPDATE wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
SET
  wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_postmeta.meta_value*1.05
WHERE
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_regular_price"
    AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = "270"
```

But it won't change prices for variable products ... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few attempts, I managed to change the price for variable products.
If someone needs to send my code:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.post_parent = wp_term_relationships.object_id
SET
  wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_postmeta.meta_value*1.05
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product_variation'
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price'
    AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '2396'
```